International flight with birds Cage set up
I am flying with my birds from California us to UK end of the year and searching for their cage.
I read many use Doskocil but I really don’t know how to set up .
Can Anyone advice me pls!
Or if anyone know alternative cage..?

There are international rules for transporting live animals via plane. It's common to find detailed requirements for dog and cat carriers (concerning size, ventilation, etc) on the websites of airlines. I would first try to find similar information for birds and then make sure the cage fulfills every one of those requirements.

This question is similar to: International travel with cockatiels (moving from the US). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you Elmy I mailed to BA and Virgin hope they reply soon ..!

Alison thank you , I checked but there many useful information but not how to set up cage. I will keep looking !
